# Angular/CSS table formatting. Div objects blocking table formatting

Tags: html, css, angular, ngfor

I'm having trouble with this table:

```
  <table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Ref</th>
      <th>Res</th>
      <th>Pom</th>
    </tr>
    <div *ngFor="let set of ics">
      <tr>
        <td style="column-span: 4">{{set.section}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr *ngFor="let ic of set.ic">
        <td>{{ic.name}}</td>
        <td>{{ic.ref}}</td>
        <td>{{ic.res}}</td>
        <td>{{ic.pom}}</td>
      </tr>
    </div>
  </table>
```

I'd like it to look like this:

```
| Name             | ref | res | pom |
| section                            |
| d1               | 1   | 2   | 3   |
| d2               | 4   | 5   | 6   | 
| another section                    | 
| d1               | 7   | 8   | 9   |
| d2               | 10  | 11  | 12  |
```

But it looks like this:

```
| Name             | ref | res | pom |
| section |
| d1      | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| d2      | 4 | 5 | 6 | 
| another section |
| d1              | 7  | 8  | 9  |
| d2              | 10 | 11 | 12 |
```

I suspect that the `<div>` object is preventing rows from seeing rows outside of the `<div>`.  That prevents them from knowing things like # columns and width.  I'm not sure what the best solution is.

I've tried the `*ngFor` in the `<table>`, and it does work, but then I get the `th` elements repeated for each set of ics and I'm trying to remove clutter.

Comment: why not use `flex` and `flex-grow`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `<ng-container>` HTML element, which tells Angular to only render the child views in the HTML and not the parent:

```html
<table style="width: 100%">
<tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Ref</th>
  <th>Res</th>
  <th>Pom</th>
</tr>
<ng-container *ngFor="let set of ics">
  <tr>
    <td style="column-span: 4">{{set.section}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let ic of set.ic">
    <td>{{ic.name}}</td>
    <td>{{ic.ref}}</td>
    <td>{{ic.res}}</td>
    <td>{{ic.pom}}</td>
  </tr>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Will mark as solved when time limit allows.